# SQL Query is slow and not using indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

```
SELECT `productTitle`, `orderCnt`, `promPCPriceStr`,
  `productImgUrl`, `oriPriceStr`, `detailUrl`,
  (SELECT count(id) FROM orders t4 
   WHERE t4.productId = t1.productId 
     AND DATE( t4.`date`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
  ) as ordertoday
FROM `products` t1
WHERE `orderCnt` > 0 
 AND `orderCnt` < 2000 
 AND `promPCPriceStr` > 0 
 AND `promPCPriceStr` < 2000 
HAVING ordertoday > 5 AND ordertoday < 2000 
order by ordertoday desc limit 150
```

This query take 18 second to finish when i run explain command on it shows this

[image: a busy cat]

it does not use the index keys !

The tables used

*Products Table*

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `detailUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `belongToDSStore` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `promPCPriceStr` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `oriPriceStr` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `orderCnt` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `productTitle` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `productImgUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `cat` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `productId` (`productId`),
 KEY `orderCnt` (`orderCnt`),
 KEY `cat` (`cat`),
 KEY `promPCPriceStr` (`promPCPriceStr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37773 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

*Orders Table*

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `oid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `countryCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`oid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 KEY `productId` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9790205 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: You create `ordertoday` with a sub-query. That is slow by itself. What makes this worse is that you're using `ordertoday` in the HAVING part. This probably means that the sub-query has to be executed for a large number of rows. (This is just a cursory analysis, I'll see if I can understand what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Yeah, you already have two answers, and I'm still trying to understand what your query is supposed to achieve... I give up. Why is there an `orderCnt` in `products`?

Comment: removing the having doesn't do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL won't use an index even if one exists on a column you search, if the values you search for appear on a large subset of the rows.

I did a test with MySQL 5.6. I created table with ~1,000,000 rows, with a column `x` with random values evenly distributed between 1 and 1000. There's an index on column `x`.

Depending on my search terms, I see the index is used if I search for a range of values matching a small enough subset of rows, otherwise it decides using the index is too much trouble, and just does a table-scan:

```
mysql> explain select * from foo where x < 50;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | range | x             | x    | 4       | NULL | 102356 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+

mysql> explain select * from foo where x < 100;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | ALL  | x             | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1046904 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

I would infer that your query's search conditions match a pretty large portion of the rows, and MySQL decides the indexes on these columns are not worth using.

```
WHERE `orderCnt` > 0 
 AND `orderCnt` < 2000 
 AND `promPCPriceStr` > 0 
 AND `promPCPriceStr` < 2000
```

If you think MySQL is making the wrong choice, you can try to use an [index hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) to tell MySQL that a table-scan is prohibitively expensive. This will urge it to use the index (if the index is relevant to the search condition).

```
mysql> explain select * from foo force index (x) where x < 100;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | foo   | range | x             | x    | 4       | NULL | 216764 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-----------------------+
```

---

I would write the query this way, without any subquery:

```
SELECT t.productTitle, t.orderCnt, t.promPCPriceStr,
  t.productImgUrl, t.oriPriceStr, t.detailUrl,
  COUNT(o.id) AS orderToday
FROM products t
LEFT JOIN orders o ON t.productid = o.productid AND o.date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
WHERE t.orderCnt > 0 AND t.orderCnt < 2000
 AND t.promPCPriceStr > 0 AND t.promPCPriceStr < 2000
GROUP BY t.productid
HAVING ordertoday > 5 AND ordertoday < 2000
ORDER BY ordertoday DESC LIMIT 150
```

When I EXPLAIN the query, I get this report:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                     | key       | key_len | ref              | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | ALL  | productId,orderCnt,promPCPriceStr | NULL      | NULL    | NULL             | 9993 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ref  | date,productId                    | productId | 8       | test.t.productId |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------+-----------+---------+------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

It still does a table-scan for `products` but it joins the relevant matching rows in `orders` with an index lookup instead of a correlated subquery.

I filled my tables with random date, to make 98,846 product rows and 215,508 orders rows. When I run the query it takes about 0.18 seconds.

Although when I run your query with the correlated subquery, it takes 0.06 seconds. I don't know why your query is so slow. You could be running on an underpowered server.

I'm running my test on a Macbook Pro 2017 with an i7 CPU and 16GB of RAM.

Comment: i'm trying to enforce the use of index on the subquery but im having no luck with it if you have some time to provide a snippet  or a suggestion on what to try that would be really helpful ,thanks again for your time.

Comment: here what i'm trying " ...from orders t4 force index (productId) WHERE "

Comment: The EXPLAIN output that you included in your original question shows that it already is using the productid index for the subquery. The problem is that even with the use of the index, the subquery is executed 31,176 times, because it's a correlated subquery.

Comment: I tried using join but it gets much worse ,and the says a possible key and its using where not the key ,also i tried limiting the filter in the query and it worked the sub query did not affect the performance

Answer (score 1):

In both tables, it is counterproductive to have both an `AUTO_INCREMENT` `PRIMARY KEY` and a `BIGINT` column that is `UNIQUE`.  Get rid of the AI column and promote the other to PK.  This may require changing some of your code, since the AI column is gone.

As for the subquery...

```
  (SELECT count(id) FROM orders t4 
   WHERE t4.productId = t1.productId 
     AND DATE( t4.`date`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
  ) as ordertoday
```

Change `COUNT(id)` to `COUNT(*)` unless you need to check `id` for being `NOT NULL` (which I doubt).

The `date` column is hidden in a function call, so no index will be useful.  So, change the date test to

```
AND t4.`date` > CURDATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
```

Then add this *composite* index.  (It will help with Karwin's reformulation, too).

```
INDEX(productId, date)
```